# Google JavaScript API - Chrome.printerProvider: Printer id format

Tags: google-chrome, printing, provider

I trying to use chrome.printerProvider to make a printing extension.
Can anyone give me an example about PrintInfo id ?
I'm request print via network and I setting PrintInfo Id by printer address but it's not working.
Here is my script:

```
chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(function callback(resultCallback) {
    resultCallback([{
      id: '192.16.1.18', // printer address
      name: 'My Printer',
    }]);
});

or

chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(function callback(resultCallback) {
    resultCallback([{
      id: 'net://192.16.1.18', // printer address
      name: 'My Printer',
    }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(
    function ( resultCallback ) {
        resultCallback( [{
      id: 'net://192.16.1.18', // printer address
      name: 'My Printer',
    }] );
    }
);
```

Comment: Please also add an explanation on how this works as expected, and don't just paste the code

Comment: Follow this document on the onGetPrintersRequested- [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider#event-onGetPrintersRequested).  ; the callback function will have a parameter which is again a function and the function should return an object of Printer info: as defined in the document: ]
[PrinterInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider#type-PrinterInfo)