# chrome extension development - printerprovider api - printer id save to pdf

Tags: google-chrome, printing

im trying to get a extension working which can grab the printed document through an event. I found the printerProvider Api. Afterwards i added the custom printer like that

```
chrome.printerProvider.onPrintRequested.addListener(function (job, status) {
    console.log(job,status)
});

chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(
    function ( resultCallback ) {
        resultCallback( [{
            id: '',
            name: 'Custom Printer',
            description: ''
        }] );
    }
);
```

Im struggling what id i have to fill in that i get the print dialog to work. I found this question which displays a way to add a network printer. ([Google JavaScript API - Chrome.printerProvider: Printer id format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903590/google-javascript-api-chrome-printerprovider-printer-id-format))

Is there a way to get the PrintJob without actually printing to a specified printer in the id or if not is it possible to print to a pdf and get the PrintJob after saving (Windows 10 adds the "Microsoft Print to PDF Printer. But i dont know its id")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.
To be able to get the pdf content you have to use this code

```
chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(
    function ( resultCallback ) {
        resultCallback( [{
            id: 'customprinter',
            name: 'Custom Printer',
            description: ''
        }] );
    }
);

chrome.printerProvider.onGetCapabilityRequested.addListener(function (printerId, resultCallback) {
    console.log(printerId);
    if(printerId == 'customprinter') {
        resultCallback(capabilities);
    }
});
```

For the capabilities variable you can use the example provided in the documentation https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#cdd-example

When you set the capabilities a preview will be displayed and you are able to print.
In onPrintRequested you will then get the printjob.